# Every time I open a terminal is located in / not in home

Tags: fedora, path, emacs, home, rxvt

I recently installed Fedora -- a fresh installation. I have a problem: every time I open a new urxvt or gnome terminal it starts in the root of the system instead of my home. I checked my /etc/passwd file and everything is seems to be correct. Also, emacs opens in the / folder as default, and before, when I was on Arch Linux, I never had this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: what does `echo $HOME` show in a terminal?

Comment: How are you starting the terminal? Do you use the command line or a desktop environment (Gnome. KDE, XFCE., Cinnamon, or something else)?

Comment: *Can* you ```cd``` to your home directory?

Comment: hy @thrig echo $HOME shows /home/rafa what is my home path

Comment: I use urxvt in i3 so I start my terminals with urxvt command, but in gnome also I have this problem.ñ @Nick

Comment: yes @G-Man I think that is problem of some configuration that I don't know or something similar.